# infinite background animations with velocity.js

Tags: velocity.js

How can i achieve an infinite background image scroll with velocity.js? 
I'm talking about something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/UHgF8/5/

this can be done with keyframes easily, but with velocity i got stack with the step (the progress) part for each interval.

```
  function start(){
      Velocity(elm, {'background-position-y': [-200, 0]},{
         duration: 4000,
         delay: 0,
         progress:function(x,y){
           debugger
         },
         complete: start

         })
       }
     start()
  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, try changing `'background-position-y'` into `backgroundPositionY`. 
It would be more helpful if you had a fiddle of the JS you're trying to run.

Second, you have a syntax error, an extra `}` after `start()`.

Lastly, unless you have complicated logic to run inside `progress` i'd suggest doing this with `@keyframes` since it will allow the animation to run in a separate thread in the background. If you *do* have some complicated logic there then there's probably no choice.